# TypeError: take_quiz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'database'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and I am trying to return a dictionary from one function and use it in another, however I keep getting this same error as said in the title. Here is my code:

```
def read_qa(filename = 'data.csv'):
    database = {}
    f_in = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f_in:
        line_list = line.strip().split(',')
        question = line_list[0]
        answers = line_list[1:]
        database[question] = answers
    f_in.close()
    return database

def take_quiz(database):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    num_questions = eval(input("How many questions?: "))
    if num_questions < len(database):
        print('The quiz will have', num_questions, 'questions.')
    else:
        print('The quiz will have', len(database), 'questions.')
    print()

read_qa()
take_quiz()



Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BA/PycharmProjects/p/b.py", line 22, in <module>
    take_quiz()
TypeError: take_quiz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'database'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you try passing the return value of the first function to the second function?

Comment: You could start by reading the [Python tutorial an functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions); your `take_quiz()` function expects something to be passed in. It looks like your `read_qa()` function *returns* something that you could pass on.

Comment: So `database = read_qa()`, then `take_quiz(database)`

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a value from read_qa(). So you must assign this function to a variable where the returned value can be stored.
Also in def of take_quiz() it expects an argument which have been called "database" in function declaration. So you need to pass a similar proper argument while calling take_quiz().
temp = read_qa(), and then ,
take_quiz(temp).
You can use any valid variable name instead of temp.
I hope this helps...